# How to compile another library into library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-build

I have an Android library which compiled with `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` and so on, because the library is a custom view. but when I build my library, the error says:

```
    Error:(8, 33) error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    Error:(9, 33) error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    Error:(21, 5) error: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView
    Error:(57, 13) error: cannot find symbol class LinearLayoutManager

Error:package R does not exist
13 warnings
:mylibrary:javadoc FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:javadoc'.

> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting):

'~/Documents/WorkSpace/MyLibrary/mylibrary/build/tmp/javadoc/javadoc.options'

Information:BUILD FAILED
```

---

**My library's `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}

apply from: 'deploy.gradle'
```

---

**My main module's `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**.**.demo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

---

**My project's `settings.gradle`**

```
include ':mylibrary', ':demo'
```

Comment: Seems like you need to add a dependency to either your main module or the library module.

Comment: @Rediska Thanks for your reply. When I run main module with my library, it works, I only added my library as dependency. But when building my library, the error appears. I need to upload the library to maven centre, so it must pass building.

Comment: Post all build.gradle files

Comment: @JaredBurrows I've updated the question, thank you.

Comment: Post your settings.gradle file

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti settings.gradle file posted, thank you.